# Data validation name different value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do I get a data validation to have a name, but give a value.

EX. In a balancing sheet for a tower defense, a unit has bleed as it's damage effect, and bleed does 0.25 tick damage, and I want a drop down to say bleed, but have 0.25 be the value so it changes the calculations of the Damage Per Second.

And I need the Data validation rule to have multiple values,

bleed:0.25

burn:0.2

hammon:0.4

scarlet burn:0.6

poison:0.125

DPS calculations,
=(K6/K8)+(K6/K12)

K6 DMG

K8 SPA

K12 drop down with dmg effect

I tried to use range names, I had a range name bleed and a value name bleed thinking it would connect, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use `switch` to convert the drop-down selection into a number:

```
=(K6/K8)+(K6/switch(K12,"bleed",0.25,"burn",0.2,etc.....))
```

If there are loads of selections possible and you'll be using them multiple times, you might want to consider creating a lookup table on another sheet and using `xlookup` as this will make for more compact formulas, but for limited selections a `switch` is ideal.